# How to split a string in Python until one of specific characters occurs from right to left?

Tags: python, string, split

What is the best way to split a string into two parts in Python from right to left until one of several characters occur?

The aim is to separate a string into two parts with a version number (beginning with either A, B or C) at the end for examples like these:

- EP3293036A1 -> EP3293036 + A1
- US10661612B2 -> US10661612 + B2
- CN107962948A -> CN107962948 + A
- ES15258411C1 -> ES15258411 + C1

My code works for splitting the string for a single character:

```
first_part = number.rpartition('A')[0]
second_part = number.rpartition('A')[1] + number.rpartition('A')[2]
```

Is there a way to have multiple arguments like ('A' or 'B' or 'C') using rpartition? Or is there a better way using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```py
import re

def split_re(s):
    return [a for a in re.split(r'.{0}(?=[ABC])+',s) if a]  # Change `ABC` to `A-Za-z` if you want a partition if any alphabetic character is present likt('A','a','z','Y')
print(split_re('EP3293036A1'))  # -> ['EP3293036', 'A1']
print(split_re('US10661612B2')) # -> ['US10661612', 'B2']
print(split_re('CN107962948A')) # -> ['CN107962948','A']
print(split_re('ES15258411C1')) # -> ['ES15258411', 'C1']
print(split_re('CA107962948A')) # -> ['C', 'A107962948', 'A']
```

Comment: The `.` at the start makes it pretty clear that you're fully aware that otherwise it wouldn't work for example for `CN107962948`, and that the current way for the same reason doesn't work for example for `CA107962948`.

Comment: What Output you get from this.

Comment: @KellyBundy I hope now solved.

Comment: Previously it returned `['', 'A10796294', 'A']` (even missing the `8`). Now it returns `['C', 'A107962948', 'A']`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I edit my answer with the respective output.

Comment: Showing a bug is an odd way to deal with it :-). The question asks for splitting into *two* parts, at *one* character, first occurrence *from the right*. Your code doesn't do any of that, as the example shows.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall). Using the regex shown, this function extracts the parts in parentheses: `(.*?)` - any characters repeated 0 or more times, non-greedy; `([AB]\d*)$` - A or B, followed by 0 or more digits, followed by the end of the string.

```
import re
lst = ['EP3293036A1', 'EP3293036B']

for s in lst:
    parts = re.findall(r'(.*?)([AB]\d*)$', s)
    print(f's={s}; parts={parts}')

# s=EP3293036A1; parts=[('EP3293036', 'A1')]
# s=EP3293036B; parts=[('EP3293036', 'B')]
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily explicit at the end. Why not `r'(.*?)([AB].*)'`?

Answer (score 1):

You example data suggests that you actually want to split between a digit and a non-digit following it. With that assumption:

```
front, back = re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)', number)
```